# Training Adapters for questions and answers Task

Tags: nlp, huggingface-transformers, large-language-model, pytorch-dataloader, adapter-transformers

I worked on text classification and sentiment analysis projects , Now I try to make Question and answer project. I tokenized the question  (input ids, attention mask). For Target, tokenize the answer , taking (input ids only and save it as labels ). After that , we load roberta model which was trained on QA datasets and try to add addapter and training adapter only for specific type of questions . I use AdapterTrainer from transformer, but it didnot accept the input i donnot know why. so , can anyone tell me what wrong here?

'''

```
from datasets import load_dataset

training_dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="/content/drive/My Drive/QA/training.csv",  split='train')
training_dataset.set_format(type="torch", columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "labels"])
testing_dataset = load_dataset("csv", data_files="/content/drive/My Drive/QA/testing.csv", split='train')
testing_dataset.set_format(type="torch", columns=["input_ids", "attention_mask", "labels"])
from transformers import AutoConfig
from adapters import AutoAdapterModel


config1 = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(
    "deepset/roberta-base-squad2"
)
model =AutoAdapterModel.from_pretrained(
     "deepset/roberta-base-squad2",
    config=config1
)
# Add a new adapter
model.add_adapter("qa", config="lora")

# Activate the adapter
model.train_adapter("qa")

import numpy as np
from transformers import TrainingArguments, EvalPrediction
from adapters import AdapterTrainer

training_args = TrainingArguments(
    learning_rate=2e-5,
    num_train_epochs=5,
    per_device_train_batch_size=16,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=16,
    logging_steps=200,
    output_dir="./training_output",
    overwrite_output_dir=True,
    # The next line is important to ensure the dataset labels are properly passed to the model
    remove_unused_columns=False,
)



trainer = AdapterTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=training_dataset,
    eval_dataset=training_dataset,
   
    compute_metrics=compute_metrics,
)
trainer.train()
```

'''
The error is

> > ---

TypeError
Traceback (most recent call

> last)  in <cell line: 1>()
> ----> 1 trainer.train()
>
> 3 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> train(self, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval,
> **kwargs)    1553                 hf_hub_utils.enable_progress_bars()    1554         else:
> -> 1555             return inner_training_loop(    1556                 args=args,    1557
> resume_from_checkpoint=resume_from_checkpoint,
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> _inner_training_loop(self, batch_size, args, resume_from_checkpoint, trial, ignore_keys_for_eval)    1858     1859                 with
> self.accelerator.accumulate(model):
> -> 1860                     tr_loss_step = self.training_step(model, inputs)    1861     1862                 if (
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> training_step(self, model, inputs)    2716         """    2717
> model.train()
> -> 2718         inputs = self._prepare_inputs(inputs)    2719     2720         if is_sagemaker_mp_enabled():
>
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/trainer.py in
> _prepare_inputs(self, inputs)    2672             raise ValueError(    2673                 "The batch received was empty, your model won't
> be able to train on it. Double-check that your "
> -> 2674                 f"training dataset contains keys expected by the model: {','.join(self._signature_columns)}."    2675             )
> 2676         if self.args.past_index >= 0 and self._past is not None:
>
> TypeError: can only join an iterable